# MS Access: relatively complex relational insertion

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have data structure like so: [phpmyadmin relation view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Foig8.png)

And I need to load data from external excel files with format that refers to many fields on these tablese. Like so:
region.region|sk.full_name|loss.loss_num|an.zn_num|contragent.full_name|loss.mark|loss.model|loss.reg_num|detail.full_name|loss.pub_date|loss.cost

So basicly I need a table-type form that allows me to do two things on adding new values to detail table:

1. Select existing values in parent tables to details table if any
   relation (imported name equal for any imported value)
2. Create new recordings on these tables, if value does not exist

My idea was to make a query like so:

```
SELECT details.znID
    ,details.statusID
    ,details.nr_reasonID
    ,zns.lossID
    ,losses.contragentID
    ,losses.skID
    ,zns.id
    ,contragents.id
    ,sk.id
    ,details.id
    ,contragents.regionID
    ,regions.id
    ,losses.id
    ,regions.region
    ,sk.full_name
    ,losses.loss_num
    ,zns.zn_num
    ,contragents.full_name
    ,losses.mark
    ,losses.model
    ,losses.reg_num
    ,details.full_name
    ,losses.pub_date
    ,losses.cost
FROM regions
INNER JOIN (
    sk INNER JOIN (
        contragents INNER JOIN (
            losses INNER JOIN (
                zns INNER JOIN details ON zns.id = details.znID
                ) ON losses.id = zns.lossID
            ) ON contragents.id = losses.contragentID
        ) ON sk.id = losses.skID
    ) ON regions.id = contragents.regionID
WHERE (((1) <> False));
```

Selecting all the refered ids and making a simple form, where any detail relations made with combo-boxes with NotInList handler. Issue I ran into was that I'm not allowed to create any new rows without specifying relation ID to detail:
So basicly access can not find an entry in the table with matching fields for any relation.

Is there any appropriate way to do such import some other way?

Comment: Is there a reason a typical subform can't work?

Comment: Only reason is all the data vill be copy-pasted from excel and I didnt figure out a way to do that with subform.